# Wordpress: Adding class selectors to the_tags(); output

Tags: wordpress, class, function, selector

How do I get the_tags() to output each tag so that it comes assigned with a unique class selector? So for example: the_tags() currently outputs something like this:

```
<a href="http://myblog.com/tag/kittens" rel="tag">kittens</a>
```

However, I'd like to output something like this:

```
<a href="http://myblog.com/tag/kittens" rel="tag" class="tag-kittens">kittens</a>
```

Is it possible to do this? If so, how? Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

It worked, thank you! This is what I did:

```
<?php
$post_tags = get_the_tags();
if ($post_tags) {
  foreach($post_tags as $tag) {
    echo '<a href="'; echo bloginfo();
    echo '/?tag=' . $tag->slug . '" class="' . $tag->slug . '">' . $tag->name . '</a>';
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: You can mark my answer as accepted or yours so other people would benefit when searching for this same problem. You can read how SO works in FAQ. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Could you post all the code that solves this problem?

Answer (score 8):

Also you can overload working of `get_the_tags();` function. 
Just add next code to your `functions.php` theme file:

```
// add custom class to tag
function add_class_the_tags($html){
    $postid = get_the_ID();
    $html = str_replace('<a','<a class="class-name"',$html);
    return $html;
}
add_filter('the_tags','add_class_the_tags');
```

Comment: Nice. I like the solution.

Answer (score 3):

this code from www.lawturn.com

```
/* SlSlib tags add class */
<?php if(has_tag()) : ?>

    <?php
    $tags = get_the_tags(get_the_ID());
      foreach($tags as $tag){
        echo '<a href="'.get_tag_link($tag->term_id).'" rel="tag" class="tag-'.$tag->name.'">'.$tag->name.'</a>';
    } ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [get_the_tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) instead, do a for loop and create your own markup.